# predict.lm throws error when dataframe is subset

Tags: r, r-caret, predict

I am trying to use the `caret::train()` function to create a linear model with leave-one-out cross-validation from a data frame with multiple response variables.  Some of the response variables I want to log transform.  Some of the other response variables have NA variables.  I am getting the following error:

```
Error in seq_len(p) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In predict.lm(trainlm, newdata = df2, type = "response") :
  calling predict.lm(<fake-lm-object>) ...
2: In seq_len(p) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

Looking through other posts, It seemed like this arose either because:

1. I subset the dataframe
2. I had NA values

I tried to remedy this by first creating a new dataframe with the appropriate columns and selecting rows with `complete.cases()`, but the problem persists.  Below is my reproducible example:

```
library(caret) # for train() function
set.seed(52) # to make reproducible
##Creating Fake Dataset
    X1<-runif(100, 2, 21)
    X2<-runif(100, 21, 40)
    X3<-runif(100, 12, 18)
    errors1<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
    errors2<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)

#multiple response variables
    Y1<-2.31+(0.52*X1)+(0.84*X2)+(2.2*X3)+(1.5*X1*X2)+(1.6*errors1)
    Y2<-5.31+(2.1*X1)+(2.2*X3)+(1.5*X1*X3)+(0.4*errors2)

##Creating an NA Value
    Y2[82]<-NA

##Dataframe with all predictors and both response variables    
    df<-data.frame(Y1, Y2, X1, X2, X3)

##Subsetting to get rid of NA and other 
    df2<-subset(df[complete.cases(df),], select=-1)

##Building the model    
    TrCtrl<-trainControl(method="LOOCV")
    trainlm<-train(log(Y2+1)~X1+X2+X3+(X1+X2)+(X1*X3)+(X2*X3)+(X1*X2*X3), method="lmStepAIC", data=df2, trControl=TrCtrl)

##Getting Prediction##
Train.Predict<-predict.lm(trainlm, newdata = df2, type = "response")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trainlm` isn't an `lm` class so `predict.lm` isn't the right function to call.

```
class(trainlm)
#> [1] "train"         "train.formula"
```

Use `predict` and let `S3` choose the appropriate method.

```
Train.Predict <- predict(trainlm, newdata = df2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Paul.  That worked great.  I also tried using caret::predict.train() and that worked too.

Comment: One other solution I just discovered is that the finalModel attribute from the output of train() is an lm object.  This would be useful if you want to get a prediction interval for example predict.lm(trainlm$finalModel, newdata=df2, interval="prediction")